# What wrong that kivy platform cannot be gotten expected behavior on macOS?

Tags: python, kivy

Please tell me what wrong on kivy platform cannot be gotten expected behavior on macOS.

### For example:

#### 1.UI acts different UI from (Mouse) pointer have indicated.

For example, three buttons was layouted on Boxlayout in a widget. the kivy widget launched action as other button was pushed, which button was different from right clicked by mouse. I felt that kivy repeat action in pushed:

- 1st:  when I pushed 1st button, launched action was as pushed 1st button.
- 2nd: when I pushed 2nd button, launched action was as pushed 1st button was pushed. However I expected 2nd button act.
- 3rd: when I pushed 2nd button, launched action was as pushed 2nd button was pushed. The action was I expected.

### 2. I could not input to TextInput UI.

If I input character into UI of "TextInput" of my kivy application, the character was inputted into editor window of IDE which launched my kivy application

### 3. Application icon did not appear.

Usually, if python code launched, 'python launcher' icon appeared in dock bar of MacOS. However, if kivy code launched, neither 'python launcher' icon nor kivy icon appeared. The has problem if a kivy code was launched from IDE, the kivy windows hid behind IDE window.

## My Environment:

- OS: macos 10.13.6
- HW: MacBookPro2016
- Python: miniconda + kivy was installed by command "conda install kivy -c conda-forge"
- Other: SDL, gstreamer etc. were installed and managed by homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved to have installed kivy from anaconda.